# Beautifying a variable templated function call

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following C++ snippet:

```
template_par<std::string> a("name", "Joh Node");
template_par<int> b("age", 23);
std::string result = templater<SomeTemplateClass>().templatize(a, b).get();
```

Which tries to implement a template engine for various purposes. The important parts of the `templater` class are:

```
template<class T>
class templater
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> kps;

public:

    template <typename T1>
    templater& templatize(template_par<T1> b)
    {
        kps.insert(make_pair(b.getKey(), to_string(b.getValue())));
        return *this;
    }


    template<typename T1, typename... Args1>
    templater& templatize(T1 first, Args1... args)
    {
        kps.insert(make_pair(first.getKey(), to_string(first.getValue())));
        return templatize(args...);
    }
}
```

ie. a template function with variable arguments .... `template_par<T>` are just template parameter classes for basic stuff. Right now as it is, this works, does the job nicely.

However, I would like to be able to shorten somehow the way I call the `templatize` method not only for aesthetics but also for a challenge... I think it would look much nicer something like:

```
  std::string result = templater<SomeTemplateClass>().templatize(
            "name" -> "Joh Node",
            "age"  -> 42
  );
```

However this approach is not feasible due to the `operator ->` being a somewhat rigid piece of C++ ... (`std::string result = templater<SomeTemplateClass>().templatize` is not the important part here, that can be hided in a friendly construct, I am more worried about the variable number of parameters)

Any good beautification ideas for the challenge above?

Comment: What's about : `templater<SomeTemplateClass>().templatize(make_templater("name", "John Doe"), make_templater("age", 42))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html), in particular the map assignment part of it, which you could co-opt here:

```
std::string result = templater<SomeTemplateClass>()
    ("Name", "Joh Node")
    ("Age", 42).templatize();
```

I would avoid getting much more creative than that, it makes the code cryptic. That said, if you want to experiment wildly, you might like my [named operators](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator), which would allow syntax such as:

```
std::string result = templater<SomeTemplateClass>().templatize(
    "name" <is> "Joh Node",
    "age"  <is> 42
);
```

Here, `is` can be any valid C++ identifier. So conventional operators are unfortunately out, but pretty  much everything flies. Even, if you *really* want to push it, `<_>`.

Comment: @Calpratt Yes, they are black magic; and no, they are not commonly used: *I* don’t currently use them in any project (I think) – hence my warning to be careful. But [at least one library](http://pfultz2.github.io/Fit/doc/html/infix/) is using them.

Comment: A very interesting solution, actually I have adopted it! Thanks a lot!